# Creating a generic lambda expression that includes parameter

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

In short I'm trying to build the equivalent of

```
Call<UnknownRegisteredClass>(r => r.UnknownMethod(...args))
```

as an `Expression<Action<T>` via reflection at runtime.

The whole concept of Expressions is quite new to me, but [everything](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) I'm finding in the docs doesn't seem to tackle it from a generic/reflection perspective but just from a more of a building expressions with known types.

So far I have managed to rig up the inside expression `r.UnknownMethod(...args)`:

```
Expression.Lambda<Action>(Expression.Call(Expression.New(actionType), actionMethod, parameterExpressions))
```

But I'm not sure how to wrap that in another level where that is call is actually made against the parameter of an `Action<T>`

Seems like it would go something like:

```
ParameterExpression instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "instance");
return Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(Expression.Call(instance, HowDoIGetMyAboveExpressionHere), new ParameterExpression[] { instance });
```

But that doesn't really work because I can't use `<T>` since I don't know the type until runtime. If anyone can see what I'm trying to do and has any examples they could point me to I would really appreciate it.

Comment: But.. Generics are a compile time thing, not a runtime thing..

Comment: You say you want that as an `Expression<Action<T>>`, so I'd expect the expression you want to build takes a parameter of type `T` and returns void. That is clearly not the case with the `Call(...)` expression you have shown. Where is the parameter of type `T`?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, the method is generic. But I need to call it at runtime.
@Sweeper The sig for the method I need to call is `void Call<T>(Expression<Action<T>> methodCall);` Just providing it a method on T that it should call. But I need to be able to do this at runtime given a request so I'm using `MakeGenericMethod(...)` with the type I get since I have the MethodInfo but I'm just not sure how to build that Expression<Action<T>> to pass in. I have the example where I can do it as just Action, but I need it to call that on the first parameter that will be provided in the Action<T>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was apparently pretty close with what I had at the end of my question. I created a local generic method that will return the expression for me and then I just call that at runtime:

```
public Expression<Action<T>> GetActionExpression<T>(Type type, MethodInfo callingMethod, List<Expression> parameterExpressions)
{
    var callLambdaParameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "p");
    var callBody = Expression.Call(callLambdaParameter, callingMethod, parameterExpressions.ToArray());
    return Expression.Lambda<Action<T>>(callBody, callLambdaParameter);
}
```

And then call it with:

```
var genericActionExpression = GetType().GetMethod(nameof(GetActionExpression)).MakeGenericMethod(actionType).Invoke(this, new object[] { actionType, actionMethod, parameterExpressions});
```

Then I can use what is now basically `r => r.UnknownMethod(...args)` to call the desired method:

```
callMethod.Invoke(this, new[] { Caller, genericActionExpression });
```